# When can I use "als" or "wie"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Benutzt man "Als immer" oder "Wie immer"? Was ist der Unterschied?

z.B.: "Sie sah so schön aus **wie immer**."
Oder kann ich sagen "Sie sah so schön **als immer**."?

Comment: Bitte beachten: in manchen *Dialekten* wird die „wie = Gleichheit, als = Unterschied“-Regel ignoriert.

Comment: @Stephie Da kann man nur mit Goethe in Faust I sagen: Da steh' ich nun, ich armer Tor! / Und bin so klug als wie zuvor.

Answer (score 7):

Mit den Wörtern **wie** und **als** werden Vergleiche gebildet und eine Beziehung zwischen Objekten ausgedrückt. Die Merkregel dazu ist:

- **wie**: damit wird Gleichheit ausgedrückt oder Objekte werden
  verglichen.
- **als**: damit wird Unterschiedlichkeit ausgedrückt oder Objekte
  werden differenziert.

Dies wirkt sich auch bei deiner Kombination mit *immer* aus.

> Sie sah so schön aus wie immer.

Diese Verwendung ist richtig, weil die Schönheit verglichen wird und die weibliche Person immer *gleich* schön ausgesehen hat.

<s>Sie sah so schön als immer (aus).</s>

Diese Verwendung ist nicht richtig, da kein Unterschied besteht. Das *(aus)* habe ich ergänzt. Richtig wäre:

> Sie sah so schön **wie** immer (aus).

Aber dann steht das (aus) im Unterschied zur ersten Lösung nur am  Ende des Satzes. Sprachlich betont die erste Lösung nach meiner Meinung den Inhalt besser.

**Edit:**

Ein gültiges Beispiel mit "als" füge ich nach einem Hinweis noch hinzu:

> Sie sah schöner aus **als** sonst. <s>immer.</s>

### Translation:

With the words **wie** and **als** comparisons are made and a relationship between objects is expressed. The rule of thumb is:

wie: with it equality is expressed or objects are compared.
als: this expresses difference or differentiates objects.
This also affects your combination from above:

> Sie sah so schön aus wie immer.

This use is correct because the beauty is compared and the female person always has the same beautiful outcome.

<s>Sie sah so schön als immer (aus).</s>

This use is not right because there is no difference. I have added the (aus). Correct would be:

> Sie sah so schön wie immer (aus).

But then, in contrast to the first solution, the (aus) is only at the end of the sentence. Linguistically, I think the first solution emphasizes the content better.

**Edit:**

After a hint in the comments I added a valid example with "als":

> Sie sah schöner aus **als** sonst. <s>immer.</s>

Comment: Schöne Antwort... ich würde noch ein gültiges Beispiel mit "als" hinzufügen, damit es ganz klar wird: `Sie sah schöner aus **als** sonst immer`

Comment: @Torsten Link - danke für den Hinweis, den ich inzwischen ergänzt habe.

Comment: `als sonst immer` klingt für mich sehr redundant. `als sonst` impliziert das `immer` nämlich schon. Besser wäre meiner Meinung nach `Sie sah schöner aus sonst`.

Comment: @Dakkaron - du hast recht. Hoffentlich hilft es auch dem OP.

Comment: Sorry, ich sehe gerade ich hab mich vorhin vertippt, gemeint war natürlich, wie in der Antwort korrekt geschrieben: `Sie sah schöner aus *als* sonst.`